# Laravel - Eloquent "relation" submit query only one time

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relation

I noticed a strange behaviour using eloquent relation.

I wrote this simple test:

```
Route::get('/myTest', function () {
    $book = \App\Models\BookModel::findOrFail(7);

    $count_start = 1;
    $count_end   = 3;
    while ($count_start <= $count_end) {
        \Log::info('  A');
        $position = $book->position->name;
        \Log::info('  B');
        sleep(5);
        $count_start++;
    }    
});
```

the **Log** reposts:

```
[2019-07-09 13:40:04] - INFO:   A
[2019-07-09 13:40:04] - DEBUG:  query: {"sql":"select * from `position` where `position`.`fk_book` = ? limit 1","time":4.66,"bindings":[7]}
[2019-07-09 13:40:04] - INFO:   B
[2019-07-09 13:40:09] - INFO:   A
[2019-07-09 13:40:09] - INFO:   B
[2019-07-09 13:40:14] - INFO:   A
[2019-07-09 13:40:14] - INFO:   B
```

The strange behaviour is that the first time the process enter in the `while`, the query is correctly execute; the second and third times (after 5sec) the query is not executed again and I do not understand why!

Is this normal? Why the relation query is executed only first time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize

```
$couny_end   = 3;
```

but use `$count_end` instead in the `for`:

```
while ($count_start <= $count_end && $position == false) {
    //...
}
```

`$count_end` is falsy and after the first iteration `$position` will no longer be `false`.

Comment: I am not a Laravel expert, but I think this is related to object hydration and caching. At the following link you can read that if you want to rehydrate, you will need to call refresh(): https://webdevetc.com/blog/laravel-features-you-may-not-know-about

Comment: @vlauciani please let me know if this was your issue.

Comment: This is a good point, I do not knew that!!! Thank you!
I'm starting to make some tests; I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Once loaded, Laravel caches the relationship values since most use cases don't require a reload every time the property is accessed.

If you want to force it to reload the relationship you can call `$book->load('position')`

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, relationship are cached.

The first time you access `$book->position`, it executes the query because the `position` model is not present yet. Once the query is executed, the `position` model is appended to the `$book` object. As a consequence, each subsequent call to `$book->position` will use that object without triggering a new database query.

This is the default behaviour, but you can leverage Laravel to do whatever you need.

If you want to load the model with the relationship in a single query (useful for large collection of objects) you can eager load it:

```
$book = BookModel::with('position')->findOrFail(7); // $book->position is immediately populated
```

If you need to force a new query when the data is already cached, you need to access and query the relationship:

```
$position = $book->position()->first(); // Force the execution of a new query
```

or

```
$book->load('position');
```